# Error handling Web Api .net core and Repository Pattern

Tags: httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi, repository-pattern

I have question about web api and Repository may be its a duplicate question.
but i tried to search on it and i did not get any satisfactory answer.
In my Repository i am getting data with the help of httpclient.

My question is that i can get an error inside my response or i can get required json data which i can map to my product class.I am returning IEnumerable.

1) If i get an error how can i bubble it up to controller and display an error to user. 
2) Return the MessageResponse instead of IEnumerable and handle it inside the controller.

What is the best way.

```
enter code here
public interface IProduct{
    Task<IEnumerable<Product>> All();
} 

public class Product:IProduct
{
      public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> All(){
          var ResponseMessage=//some response.
       }
}
```

Comment: Add an error handler to the pipeline that executes before the request, the handler is just a class that wraps the execution code in a try catch, then just handle each error  and clean out the details you don't want to send to the user

Comment: @johnny5, Thanks for your tip, highly appreciated, can you please give me c# code example to understand your point more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could customize a `ApiException` which is used to get the error message of the response, and call the `UseExceptionHandler` in your startup.cs ,refer to the following :

**ProductRep**

```
 public class ProductRep : IProduct
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    public ProductRep(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> All()
    {
        List<Product> productlist = new  List<Product>();

        var response = await _client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44357/api/values/GetProducts");

        string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == false)
        {
            JObject message = JObject.Parse(apiResponse);
            var value = message.GetValue("error").ToString(); 
            throw new ApiException(value);                
        }

        productlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(apiResponse);

        return productlist;
    }

    public class ApiException : Exception
    {
        public ApiException(string message): base(message)
        { }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(a => a.Run(async context =>
            {
                var feature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
                var exception = feature.Error;

                var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = exception.Message });
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
            }));
```